# haproxy ssh path based routing

Tags: ssh, haproxy

I have a use case where I want to use haproxy to forward ssh requests to different back end servers.

I want a user to be able to ssh to proxy.example.com/server1 and haproxy forwards the request on to the backend ssh server.  The path in the url is just to differentiate each server for the user.  In the back end server, there won't be a path.

Is this even possible?  If I have haproxy set to tcp mode to listen on port 22, will it even understand the request with the path?

Comment: That's not even possible.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging and testing.  This really isn't viable for what I'm trying to achieve.